# Getting error when trying to update location

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

i try to update the user current location, my relevant code is this :

```
#pragma mark-
#pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    float latitude=newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    float longitude=newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    TopStationAppDelegate *topStation=(TopStationAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    topStation.latitudeUtilisateur=latitude;
    topStation.longitudeUtilisateur=longitude;
    NSLog(@"%f",latitude);
    NSLog(@"%f",longitude);
    NSLog(@"position updated");
    //[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
}
```

the `didFailWithError` method return me this stack:

```
ERROR,Time,332840118.515,Function,"void CLClientHandleDaemonDataRegistration(__CLClient*, mach_port_t, const CLDaemonCommToClientRegistration*, const __CFDictionary*)",server did not accept client registration 2
2011-07-20 09:35:18.525 TopStation[764:207] didFailWithError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 1.)"
```

Can you please help me there? thanx in advance :)

Comment: are you working on simulator?

Comment: yes, i test currently on simulator :)

Comment: cllocationmanager does not work on simulator thats why u r getting this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the previous comment stated, the simulator version you are working with just won't work for location based stuff. Your best bet (if you are a paid developer) is to download the new Xcode 4.2 that does allow you to manipulate location data and actually use the simulator.

If you aren't a paid developer, you will have to test on device.

Check this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922507/is-iphone-simulator-capable-of-showing-heading-and-latitude-longitude/7236080#7236080) for some links if you are a paid dev. You can check out the WWDC videos on how to use the simulator for location testing.